# How can I create mutually exclusive radio buttons with different names?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons that belong to the same category, but I want to name them differently and make them mutually exclusive. How do I do that? Based on the selected value, I do different actions, and I can't access them if they have the same name.

Comment: If you need different names you'll have to alter the radio's name upon submit of the form.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why can't you access them if they have the same name? **You can add IDs** (you should), you can distinguish by value or just count them and use the n-th element.

You **should give radiobuttons the same name** to make the browser understand they are exclusive.

You could (but should not) hack around this, and give each object a different name. Then add an onSelect/onClick handler for each object, and when the event fires, "uncheck" the other buttons. This is dirty and should be avoided.

Comment: As I want to perform different action , based on selected value. Action code is written in Java.

Comment: Well why not look at the value of the parameter in your Java code and use it to decide what to do?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did finally.

Answer (score 15):

Radio buttons require the same name to be mutually exclusive. However, they can have different ID attribute values, if you want to manipulate them individually with JavaScript.

There are lots of ways to get the selected value with jQuery:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />


// value of checked input tag of type 'radio'
var selectedValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();

// value of checked input tag having name of 'foo'
var selectedValue = $('input[name=foo]:checked').val();

// value of the first checked radio button, regardless of name
var selectedValue = $('input:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change the name, you can access the DOM and it's elements through JavaScript.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="X" id="myElement" />

<script>   document.getElementById('myElement').name = 'text'; </script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_ex_dom.asp